# MySQL 'Unrecognized Data Type' When Creating a Table

Tags: mysql

I'm creating a materialized view in MySQL to reduce server load when data is queried from a bunch of other tables(one product at a time). My simplified code is as follows:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `db`.`view_stock`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `db`.`view_stock` (
SELECT A.title, on_order,(stock-sales) AS 'Stock' FROM
    (SELECT SUM(`bought_products`.`qty`) AS 'on_order'
    ,`bought_products`.product_id, title FROM 
    `bought_products` GROUP BY product_id)
    A, 
    (SELECT SUM(num) AS `stock`,product_id FROM plugins__stock GROUP BY 
    product_id) 
    B,
    (SELECT SUM(`bought_products`.`qty`) AS `sales`
    ,`bought_products`.`product_id` FROM `storage__bought_products` JOIN 
    `plugins__orders` WHERE `bought_products`.`order_id` = 
    `plugins__orders`.`id` AND 
        ((`plugins__orders`.`status` = 'paid') OR
        (`plugins__orders`.`status` = 'shipped'))
    GROUP BY product_id)
    C
WHERE B.product_id = A.product_id AND C.product_id = A.product_id ORDER BY on_order)
```

When I run the query by itself it works and returns the data as expected. However, when I try to create the table in the above context, I get the following error: `Unrecognized data type. (near 'A')` This error is highlighted at the beginning of the query where 'A' is first mentioned (near 'A.title').

Heres a sample result:

```
Title        on_order        Stock
'Widget'     6               15
'Gadget'     3               10
```

I've tried using other ways to declare the table, but it seems like nothing is working. Does anyone have any ideas?

The table structure of `bought_products` is:

```
CREATE TABLE `bought_products` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `order_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `product_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `qty` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `stock_count` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)
```

The table structure of `plugins__stock` is:

```
CREATE TABLE `plugins__stock` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `product_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `num` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)
```

The table structure of `plugins__orders` is:

```
CREATE TABLE `plugins__orders` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `name` tinytext NOT NULL,
  ...
  `status` enum('open','paid','shipped','deleted')
)
```

These are obviously shortened to keep the post length short.

Comment: Can you provide the structure of your Table(s) so that I can better grasp what your trying to accomplish. It looks like your trying to call values that have not been defined in the table.

Comment: I updated the question with the table structure. I checked to make sure that I'm not referencing empty/nonexistent columns.

Comment: There seems to be, to me at least, some undeclared values in your question. Title, stock_sales, on_order. I know it may not be the best answer but I would reference on how best to structure your materialized view. [HERE](http://www.fromdual.com/mysql-materialized-views)